# How to stop or abort a nav2 navigation in ros2 foxy?

Tags: navigation, ros2

i'd like to know how could i stop or abort a nav2 navigation with a python node ! I can't find the information on my own. I saw that the simple commander API is not support with ros2 foxy so i cannot install it.

I'm using ros2 foxy.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance,

Sacha

I've found many methods but nothing is working

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no safe way to kill a node except by closing the terminal, or `CTRL+C`. This being said, I have two "hacky" suggestions:

- Run nav2 in a separate window and deal with it separately from everything else.

- Control the flow of information by remapping the topics. Create a node to subscribe to the nav2 topics and publish a copy of those topics with a different name. That way, you can control if the topics are published or not.

Comment: hi, thank you very much for your awnser, i will consider those options, would you know if it would be easier to pause a navigation and tu resume it ? If yes, do you know the way to do it ?

Thanks in advance